# Tying device id to contact?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Can someone demonstrate the proper way  to tie the device  id to an existing  contact  in marketing  cloud. I am experimenting  enabling  push notifications, which have been successful except, now I am at the point  where I want  to link my contacts  to thier  device id's. I am looking  for any documentation, tips, and/or best practices.

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDK's both have convenience methods that allow you to set a Contact Key (formerly Subscriber Key).  This key will tie the current device's registration to the contact with the same Contact Key.

Android: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/contact-key.html

iOS: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/features/subscriber-key.html

An example of the Android Implementation might look similar to this for version 5.x:

```
    MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk(new MarketingCloudSdk.WhenReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void ready(MarketingCloudSdk marketingCloudSdk) {
            RegistrationManager.Editor registrationEditor = marketingCloudSdk.getRegistrationManager().edit();
            registrationEditor.setContactKey("user@email.com" /* or cell number, etc */); // ContactKey must always be unique in the Marketing Cloud Servers

            registrationEditor.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Bill! I did see that in the documentation when I was implementing the SDK. However, when I call this method there is nothing committed to SFMC. Perhaps, I am not calling this method correctly.

Comment: I am calling that method directly after my authentication method. This is the flow: Login attempt with email and password --> if success, then call setContactKey() with email.toString() passed in. Is there a reason this would not work? Can setContactKey() only be called within the application class?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using @Rudy?  If you're using 5+ then please ensure you're calling `commit()` after making any edits to the device/contact registration.

Comment: I understand ContactKey can be set/link using the method.  If someone downloaded an app, how do we know to which existing contactKey he/she should be linked to?

Comment: User validation would be part of your business logic.  If your Contact Key is an e-mail, for instance, you'd want to validate the user's e-mail and upon success assign that value in the SDK.  I would not assign values based on unverified user input.